# How to remove Synaptic touchpad driver (and still have [Logitech] touchpad work)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, touchpad, synaptics

I have two machines, both with Logitech touch pads.  One is running 14.04.5, and (apparently) has no Synaptics driver controlling the touchpad.  I don't know how the touchpad works there, presumably it uses some form of emulation.  But here's the thing: It works *perfectly*:  click-and-drag, two-finger scrolling, everything is just perfect.  No adjustments required.

My other machine is running 16.04.1 and has the Synaptics driver (apparently) installed.  And it's just *terrible*:  I can't get click-and-drag to work reliably, moving the cursor across the screen ends up doing a select of all the text in my browser window about 30% of the time, and it's otherwise just pathetic. Virtually unusable.

I have tried using `synclient` to set various parameters to make it less sensitive or whatever, following several guides here on AskUbuntu, and I can't get it anywhere close to as good as the way it works on my 14.04 machine.

So here's my question:  How do I remove the Synaptics crud while still allowing my touchpad to work (as it did in 14.04) in some kind of emulation mode?  I did some sort of "disable" on the Synaptics driver (don't remember where I found it), but then the touchpad was completely dead.

Any ideas for how to make it work like it did in 14.04?

Comment: Are the touchpads exactly the same hardware (same controller chip, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, identical.  I can't find the model number here, but they were bought at the same time.

Comment: I'm hoping that maybe if I can _disable_ the Synaptics driver in 16.04, the emulation (or whatever it's using) would allow it to work like it does in 14.04.

Comment: Well, not much in the way of responses, so maybe I'll just make this my personal note-taking post.

The main problem is with getting _selects_ while just moving the mouse.  I.e., just moving the mouse across the screen will do a text select on whatever window the cursor was over, like a double-click-and-drag operation would.  I've tried setting the FingerLow param a little lower, but I still get the same effect.

I wish there were a debug mode for this stupid thing.

Comment: Okay, wow.  I've discovered that the problem is actually a phantom click coming from the driver (definitely not the hardware!) on a semi-random basis.

I noted with equal frustration that my screen-blanker was failing after a random amount of time -- the screen would just suddenly light up with an interaction.  I thought this was a different problem with gnome-screensaver, as I had been having some trouble with it just plain not working lately (more 16.04 nonsense!).

Comment: So now I just have to find the source of this phantom click...

Comment: Are you sure it's not the hardware? Maybe it is too sensitive to pressure or something similar? Can you click by blowing on the touchpad? :)